# UITableViewCell error call tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: select, uitableview, call

I want to access the UITableViewCell that is after the one that is selected and select that one,

```
int b = lastIndexPath.row + 1;   //lastIndexPath references to the current selected cell index path

NSIndexPath *myNextIndex = [[NSIndexPath alloc]initWithIndex:b];

[self tableView:table didSelectRowAtIndexPath:myNextIndex];
```

so up to this point everything works fine, the b value is 2. but when the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and I want to get the value of i,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

int i = indexPath.row;

//some other stuff

}
```

I get the value 81809923 for i, but the value of i should be 2.

I don't know why this would happen. if anyone has any idea please help.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positions in a `UITablleView` are keyed by both section and row (even if your table only has a single section).  The iOS SDK adds a [utility method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) specifically for the purpose of making it easier to work with table views.

In this case, you would use it like:

```
NSIndexPath* myNextIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:b inSection:0];  //call 'retain' if you need to
```

As for your `81809923` value, that is probably random garbage that happened to be in memory, since your original code does not assign any value to the `row` field of the `NSIndexPath`.